# TempDB Transaction log not releasing space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction-log, tempdb, checkpoint

Every time I complete a transaction in tempdb, the temp log grows, however the log doesn't seem to release the space once the transaction has completed.The log usage percent is 43.4%  but seems to increase in around 4% increments.

When I look for open transactions (`sys.dm_exec_sessions`), there are none. Yet the `log_reuse_wait_desc` in `sys.databases` shows 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'. When I query the `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions` DMV, it shows only work table.

I'm unsure of how I can release this space from the tempdb transaction log.

I've just run a manual checkpoint and that seems to free up the space so I'm not sure as to why the space isn't being freed up on it's own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `log_reuse_wait_desc` is only updated when SQL Server attempts to clear the log.  In other words, it's not necessarily a "live" view of whether the log can be cleared or not.  Paul Randal explains that in his blog post "[Why is log_reuse_wait_desc saying LOG_BACKUP after doing a log backup?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-is-log_reuse_wait_desc-saying-log_backup-after-doing-a-log-backup/)".

In the case of `tempdb`, which uses the `SIMPLE` recovery model, SQL Server attempts to clear the log whenever a `CHECKPOINT` is issued.  This is why doing a manual `CHECKPOINT` frees up the space, as you mentioned.

SQL Server is a lot less aggressive about doing automatic `CHECKPOINT`s on `tempdb`, both because it uses the `SIMPLE` recovery model, and because it is by definition "temporary" information.  So there's no need to constantly persist it to disk.  This is a performance optimization specific to `tempdb`.

Per [another blog post by Paul Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/what-does-checkpoint-do-for-tempdb/), the details are as follows:

- automatic `CHECKPOINT` operations on `tempdb` are only done when the log usage reaches 70%
- dirty pages are not written to disk on automatic `CHECKPOINT` (its primary purpose it to clear the log)

The "work table" rows in `dm_tran_active_transactions` are normal behavior, and shouldn't prevent the log from being cleared.  You can read more about that in this Q&A:

[SQL Server sys.dm_tran_active_transactions long running transaction worktable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/243283/6141)